# If $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f$ is monotone, prove that $f(x)=ax$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a monotone function satisfying $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \quad \forall \ x,y\in\Bbb{R}$$ Prove that $$\exists a\in \Bbb R,\forall x\in\Bbb{R}, f(x)=ax $$

I proved that $f(x)=ax \quad \forall x\in \Bbb{Q}$. Assume it is monotonically increasing. Now let $\alpha$ be any irrational number. Then, choose sequences $\{x_n\}$ increasing to $\alpha$ and $\{y_n\}$ decreasing to $\alpha$. Thus, $$f(x_n)\le f(\alpha)\le f(y_n)$$ i.e. $$ax_n\le f(\alpha)\le ay_n$$ Now, letting $n\to \infty$,  we get $f(\alpha)=a\cdot \alpha$

Is my proof correct for irrationals?

Comment: is your function continuous in a point ?

Comment: f is not given to be continuous

Comment: @idm: That is not necessary here, because the function is monotone. (It turns out that the function is always continuous, but you don't need to assume it.)

Comment: More or less. The function might be monotone decreasing in which case the inequalities would be the other way round. You have established uniqueness. That does not establish existence, but in this case that is obvious.

Comment: @almagest edited now

Comment: Might be of use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation

Comment: I think that $r$ is not the best name for an irrational number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I first thought to use $i$ instead of $r$, but $r$ looks better to me.

Comment: It interferes somewhat with readability, since $r$ is a canonical name for a rational number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so what would be best, I'll change it

Comment: Minor point. don't worry about it. A not bad name is $\alpha$.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cQj8c.png

Comment: You also want to point out that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are sequences of *rational numbers* as this is needed to go from $f(x_n)$ to $ax_n$. If this is for a course you also might want to add "we get $f(\alpha) = a\alpha$ *by the squeeze theorem*".

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can add that $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ are rational sequences.And letting $n\to\infty$ we get $a\cdot\alpha\leq f(\alpha)\leq a\cdot\alpha$ this implies $f(\alpha)=a\cdot\alpha$ but those are just small things(for clearness of proof)

Comment: For completeness you can add that the number $a$ that you are after is simply $f(1)$.